# Stack Overflow Careers links broken on the Android app

Tags: bug, jobs, android-app

It leads to "not found".

For example:

https://clc.stackoverflow.com/jobs/131738/php-engineer-help-scout?an=47Saei7mhOkVD24GhuBQTgcGIGAEEb8YG1gYGOSZuJkYchuZGRjYGUQPhD_faalad92O4bKF48LlbpFSVjkA&cr=229741&ct=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fjobs%2F131738%2Fphp-engineer-help-scout&sig=XXu8SBYVJ7cawQ

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-N910V

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (N910VVRS2CPL1)